# Extracting the values of other columns based on the values I get from MAX()/MIN() on SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a column with names of spots and different XY coordinates. I am trying to get the max(X), max(Y), min(X), min(Y) for distinct spots names. However, for each min/max coordinate, I want to get its corresponding X or Y. Here is the pedInfo table:

| pedestrian | AtSpot | x | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 233 | tickets | 234 | 54 |
| 233 | tickets | 124 | 35 |
| 233 | tickets | 150 | 200 |
| 233 | tickets | 23 | 70 |

I wrote the following query to get the MAX/MIN X/Y values, but I am not sure how to get the corresponding X/Y for each of them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(AtSpot), MAX(X) AS max_X, MAX(Y) AS max_Y, MIN(X) AS min_X, MIN(Y) AS min_Y 
FROM pedInfo GROUP BY AtSpot;
```

The expected output:

| AtSpot | maxX | maxX_Y | minX | minX_Y | maxY | maxY_X | minY | minY_X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tickets | 234 | 54 | 23 | 70 | 200 | 150 | 35 | 124 |

Comment: Serves no purpose to use DISTINCT with GROUP BY.

Comment: So each spot name can have multiple coordinates? Can any X or Y be repeated for any spot name? Edit question to provide representative data sample as text table.

Comment: yes, because these spots are not points but rather surfaces. It is technically impossible to have the X Y repeated for any of the spots.

Comment: Why is grouping not on pedestrian field? Will X always be 3 digits and Y always 2 digits?

Comment: I don't mean XY pair, I mean just X or just Y could repeat for a spot group. Which should definitely be possible. In which case there are ties for Max and Min values.

Answer (score 0):

I have two approaches to consider.

1. First step is to build aggregate query but without DISTINCT as it serves no purpose. Next, build another query that has 4 instances of table and one of each will INNER JOIN to aggregate query with compound linking on AtSpot fields and one of the aggregate fields to appropriate X or Y field. I can only see this possible as long as neither X nor Y values repeat for any spot group. Repeats mean ties for Max and Min values and this becomes non-manageable.  Following is the second query:

```
SELECT qMaxMin.AtSpot, MaxX.x, MaxX.y, MaxY.x, MaxY.y, MinX.x, MinX.y, MinY.x, MinY.y
FROM pedInfo AS MinY 
INNER JOIN (pedInfo AS MinX 
INNER JOIN (pedInfo AS MaxY 
INNER JOIN (pedInfo AS MaxX
INNER JOIN qMaxMin 
ON (MaxX.x = qMaxMin.max_X) AND (MaxX.AtSpot = qMaxMin.AtSpot)) 
ON (MaxY.y = qMaxMin.max_Y) AND (MaxY.AtSpot = qMaxMin.AtSpot)) 
ON (MinX.x = qMaxMin.min_X) AND (MinX.AtSpot = qMaxMin.AtSpot)) 
ON (MinY.y = qMaxMin.min_Y) AND (MinY.AtSpot = qMaxMin.AtSpot);
```

2. Second approach requires a unique identifier field such as autonumber. Build four TOP N nested queries. Build a 5th query that uses one of the 4 as 'parent' and joins the other 3 on AtSpot fields.  Again, repeats of X or Y mean ties. This method will pull one - most likely record with the highest ID value. Following are the 4 TOP N queries:

qMaxX

```
SELECT * FROM pedINFO WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM pedInfo AS Dup WHERE Dup.AtSpot = pedInfo.AtSpot ORDER BY Dup.X DESC);
```

qMaxY

```
SELECT * FROM pedINFO WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM pedInfo AS Dup WHERE Dup.AtSpot = pedInfo.AtSpot ORDER BY Dup.Y DESC);
```

qMinX

```
SELECT * FROM pedINFO WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM pedInfo AS Dup WHERE Dup.AtSpot = pedInfo.AtSpot ORDER BY Dup.X);
```

qMinY

```
SELECT * FROM pedINFO WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM pedInfo AS Dup WHERE Dup.AtSpot = pedInfo.AtSpot ORDER BY Dup.Y);
```

Comment: The output I am getting from this is assigning maxY to maxX.y and vice versa and the same for the minimum. It is not getting any new coordinates from the pedInfo table. Maybe I should clarify further. What I am trying to do is basically, let's say for example, max_Y for the AtSpot "tickets" is located in row 30. Hence, I want the X in row 30 ..etc

Comment: Output from which method? I tested and both worked. Second method is probably safer one. Edit question to show more representative dataset as well as expected output from that set.

Comment: I have edited the question. I tried the first approach.

Comment: I tested with that data and output is correct with both methods. Except I show each pair as X Y, not Y X but you can arrange the fields however you want.

Comment: I considered a third approach which involves concatenating the X and Y fields. I didn't think that output would be useful. But I could elaborate if you're interested.